# Outlook VBScript Signature Change Color and Font w/o Line Break

Tags: vbscript

I have a very particular client who wants all employee email signatures formatted in a very specific way. The issue I am having is the client would like it to be formatted as w:  where the "w:" is formatted in blue and the hyperlink in black, both Arial 9pt.

I am not able to get this to work without either adding in unwanted line breaks or without the entire signature being formatted to black.

```
'Website
objSelection.Font.Name = "Arial"
objSelection.Font.Size = 9
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(27,161,226)
objSelection.Font.Bold = False
objSelection.Font.Italic = False
objSelection.TypeText strSymbol_W

objSelection.Font.Bold = False
objSelection.Font.Italic = False
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add (objSelection.Range, strWebsite, , ,strWebsite)
Set objSelection = objLink()
objSelection.Font.name = "Arial"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
objSelection.Font.Size = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look a little more like this:

```
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range, strWebsite, "", "", strWebsite)
objLink.Range.Font.name = "Arial"
objLink.Range.Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
objLink.Range.Font.Size = 9
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Interesting how selecting the Range itself fixed it instead of the Selection.